# how to fix connection error in a telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I started to write a telegram bot and I used the freeCodeCamp example for that.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import requests
import re
contents = requests.get('https://random.dog/woof.json').json()
image_url = contents['url']

def get_url():
    contents = requests.get('https://random.dog/woof.json').json()
    url = contents['url']
    return url

def get_image_url():
    allowed_extension = ['jpg','jpeg','png']
    file_extension = ''
    while file_extension not in allowed_extension:
        url = get_url()
        file_extension = re.search("([^.]*)$",url).group(1).lower()
    return url
def bop(bot, update):
    url = get_url()
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=url)


def main():
    updater = Updater('<MY-PRIVATE-BOT-TOKEN>')
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('bop', bop))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After running this code I got this error. Also, I get this error after running any telegram bot I write.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='random.dog', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /woof.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026811517F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workbot/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    contents = requests.get('https://random.dog/woof.json').json()
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='random.dog', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /woof.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026811517F10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

> I also have to use proxy or VPN to connect to telegram because of filtering.

> I got another connection error in an echo bot. I used the telegram bot documentation code. I got this error:

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000199A2C37DF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workbot/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    contents = requests.get('https://google').json()
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\workbot\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000199A2C37DF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Comment: Your **BOT token** was in the question. I removed it, but it's still visible in the history. Consider renewing the token at @botFather to prevent other people abusing it!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: `getaddrinfo failed` means that your DNS server can't resolve the host `random.dog`. This seems like a connectivity issue between your server and that host - so you might want to proxy/vpn that part as well.

Comment: but I had this problem even when I was building a simple echo bot